# Why Spring batch executing as singleton instead of multithread

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am invoking a spring batch job through quartz scheduler, which should run every 1 minute. 
When the job runs the first time, the ItemReader is opened successfully and the job runs. However when the job attempts to run a second time, it's using the same instance it did the first time which is already initialized and receiving "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream is already initialized. Close before re-opening." I have set scope as step for both itemreader and itemwriter.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in configuration?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<import resource="context.xml"/>
<import resource="database.xml"/>   
<bean id="MyPartitioner" class="com.MyPartitioner" />
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.MyProcessor" scope="step" />

<bean id="itemReader" class="com.MyItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sql" value="query...."/>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.MyRowMapper" scope="step"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<job id="MyJOB" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="masterStep">
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="MyPartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </partition>
    </step>
</job>
<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="mysqlItemWriter" processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="100"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mysqlItemWriter" class="com.MyItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[      
            query.....
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>

<property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="com.MyPreparedStatementSetter" scope="step"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Quartz job invoker-

```
Scheduler scheduler = new    StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties").getScheduler();
JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("QUARTZJOB", "QUARTZJOB");
JobDetail jobDetail =     JobBuilder.newJob("com.MySpringJobInvoker").withIdentity(jobKey).build();
jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("jobName", "SpringBatchJob");
SimpleTrigger smplTrg = newTrigger().withIdentity("QUARTZJOB", "QUARTZJOB").startAt(new Date(startTime))  
                            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(frequency).withRepeatCount(repeatCnt))
                            .forJob(jobDetail).withPriority(5).build();
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, smplTrg);
```

Quartz job -

```
public class MySpringJobInvoker implements Job
{
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException
{
    JobDataMap data = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();

    ApplicationContext applicationContext =ApplicationContextUtil.getInstance();

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) applicationContext.getBean("jobLauncher");
    org.springframework.batch.core.Job job = (org.springframework.batch.core.Job) applicationContext.getBean(data.getString("jobName"));
    JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("myparam","myparam").addString(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis(),Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
}
```

}

Singletonclass -

public class ApplicationContextUtil
{
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

```
public static synchronized ApplicationContext getInstance()
{
    if(applicationContext == null)
    {
        applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myjob.xml");
    }
    return applicationContext;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see anything obvious wrong.  Are you using java config at all in this application or only XML based configuration?

Comment: I am using following code in MyItemReader class to set dynamic parameters to SQL query.      @BeforeStep
    public void setStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution)
    { setSql("myquery");}. No other java configuration other than this.

Answer (score 1):

what are the parameters that you are passing to the Spring Batch job from Quartz? Could you post the exception stack trace?

If your trying to execute the second instance of the batch with the same parameters - it won't work. Spring Batch identifies a unique instance of the job based on parameters passed - so every new instance of the job requires different parameters to be passed.

Comment: I updated code to pass current system time along with other parameters to job, but error still exist.  JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("myparam", myparam).addString(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()),Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters(); . Is there anything else needs to be added/updated ?

Comment: This looks correct. How are you executing the job every one min? Whats the command that you are using to run your job? Are you using a CommandLineJobRunner?

Comment: Following is my job launcher code - ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myjob.xml");
JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) applicationContext.getBean("jobLauncher");
Job job = applicationContext.getBean("myjob");
JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("myparam","myparam").addString(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()),Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();
JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param); . CommandLineJobRunner can't be used with quartz or multithread application ?

Comment: Command line runner can be used by multithread application as well as quartz... Your code looks OK to me... Would have expected it to work... Unless the application context is not being reloaded

Comment: So you mean I shouldn't load myjob.xml file again when the quartz gets triggered second time? Instead I should only load the myjob from already existing context(myjob.xml)? As per current setup the whole set of code will get executed each time job get triggered.

Comment: No I mean **you should** load you XML again when you trigger the job a second time and looking at your code I would have expected it to work!

Comment: When I made loading of "myjob.xml" singleton I am not receiving any error and it's working fine. But I think this is not proper approach, is there any other way than this?

Comment: You could try using the command line runner. This page has a good article explaining how to use it: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/run-spring-batch-job-with-commandlinejobrunner/

Comment: How did you make the loading of myjob.xml singleton? You need to post more code, your quartz schedule config as well as your "class" that is being executed by this quartz schedule

Comment: I've updated the question with quartz setup and other details. I am not using QuartzDataBean which spring provides, as per my business requirement.

Comment: You are **NOT** reloading the application context every time you run the job. You should.

This should be,
public static synchronized ApplicationContext getInstance()
{
        applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myjob.xml");
    return applicationContext;
}

load a new context on every time try to run the job!

Comment: That's the earlier configuration I was using and it was giving me the above said exception, but when I changed to this approach I am not receiving any error.

Comment: **confused** which approach was giving you error and what worked?

Comment: Loading myjob.xml everytime "public static synchronized ApplicationContext getInstance() { applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myjob.xml"); return applicationContext; } " is not working, where as using singleton I posted above it's working.

Comment: Ok that doesn't make sense... Loading everytime should have worked and the singleton should not have worked

Comment: Correct, but I am unable to find why it's not working in this case. I could clearly see when the job gets triggered second time if the first instance not finished yet then 2nd instance will use 1st instance's itemreader query instead of fresh query as per job configuration. ?